# Chrome Extension: Can Javascript intercept a file download and parse the data

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension to automate one of my daily tasks, part of the task is downloading a .csv file and manipulating the data. As part of the automation I want to grab the file with Javascript and make the script manipulate it.

The problem is grabbing this file with an XMLHttpRequest would be a nightmare because they send heaps of unique IDs to verify the user and it'd be a nightmare to work out where they come from.

I can easily click the button using javascript which starts the file download, but is there a way that javascript can intercept this request and parse the CSV? I'm thinking if its not possible with plain javascript I might be able to do it with the HTML5 file API?

Comment: Please explain the "nightmare" part with more technical details :)

Comment: @BorisSmus lol, basically I don't think the provider wants people automatically scraping large amounts of these downloads (I'm only doing 1) so they've made it extremely difficult to follow their code, they have all these IDs they post to the server to get the download. I could probably spend a week figuring it all out but I was hoping there'd be an easier solution that wasn't as hard to maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try using the [webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) API. When the download request is you want is made you can cancel it with this method, get the complete URL being used, and make that same request from JavaScript.

Comment: The WebRequest API is no longer experimental; it's supported

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by accessing the file's content with an AJAX request to `file://{filepath}` once the file has been downloaded. You just need to add the `file://*`permission to your manifest file.

To get the downloaded file's path in the local system, use [`chrome.downloads.search`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search) and get the `filename`property.